# MongoDB Java API: Difference between com.mongodb.DBCollection.Save() and com.mongodb.DBCollection.Insert()?

Tags: java, api, mongodb

It looks these two methods both save a BasicDbObject to a collection instance.What is the difference between these two methods?
com.mongodb.DBCollection.Insert()
com.mongodb.DBCollection.Save()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Save can only save one object at a time.  If _id is provided and it already exists, the new document will overwrite the previously existing one.  If it doesn't exist, it will do an insert.

Insert can take a single object or an ArrayList of objects and do a "bulk insert" of them.

If you give an existing _id to an insert it will cause a duplicate Id exception.

Answer (score 3):

`.insert` is only for insert, while `.save` can do insert or update.

com.mongodb.DBCollection.Save

> Saves an object to this collection (does insert or update based on the
>   object _id).

Answer (score 0):

Save will either insert or update if the document has a set _id and insert will just insert.

You can read more about it here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating/#Updating-{{save%28%29}}inthemongoshell