# Mongodb: Can't save a new element added into BasicDBList

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am trying to add an element to a BasicDBList array and save it back to Mongodb, but when I check the result, it is not written. What did I do wrong? I use java driver version 2.7.2.

```
DBObject dbObject = coll.findOne(dbQuery);

BasicDBList unreadMsgs = (BasicDBList) dbObject.get("unreadMsgs");

Logger.debug("before incrementing unreadMsgs" + dbObject.toString());

unreadMsgs.add(new BasicDBObject("id", 1).append("unreadMsg", 1));
Logger.debug("after incrementing unreadMsgs : " + dbObject.toString());
coll.save(dbObject);
Logger.debug("check result: " + coll.findOne(dbQuery).toString());
```

before incrementing unreadMsgs{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "515c5eb88e3278e9c9d55867"} , "unreadMsgs" : [ ]}

after incrementing unreadMsgs : { "_id" : { "$oid" : "515c5eb88e3278e9c9d55867"} , "unreadMsgs" : [ { "id" : 1 , "unreadMsg" : 1}]}

check result: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "515c5eb88e3278e9c9d55867"} , "unreadMsgs" : [ ]}

Comment: Depending on your configuration you could be reading before the write has actually happened. Have you checked a few seconds later directly from mongo shell?

Comment: yes, I did check a while later directly from mongo shell. The same result.

Comment: If you use the ACKNOWLEDGED writeconcern (default with MongoClient or if you use a Mongo: `mongo.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED);`) you can check if there was an error: `WriteResult result = coll.save(dbObject);` and see if `result.getError()` returns an error.

Comment: Thanks for your method. I found the real problem. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the coll.save(dbObject) is not updating anything.

It works as an insert and, since the _id already exists in the collection, you are getting a duplicateKey exception (you are just not seeing it because of configuration).

You have to use an update, [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#crud-update-update) is how

Comment: If you want your app to catch mongo exceptions try setting the writeconcern of your mongoClient to 1.  Possible values are:     **-1 NONE** No exceptions are raised, even for network issues-
    **0 NORMAL** Exceptions are raised for network issues, but not server errors 
    **1 SAFE** Exceptions are raised for network issues, and server errors; waits on a server for the write operation

    **2 REPLICAS_SAFE** Exceptions are raised for network issues, and server errors; waits for at least 2 servers for the write operation

Comment: According to javadoc, DBCollection.save: "Saves an object to this collection (does insert or update based on the object _id)." Since this object already exists, shouldn't save actually do an update operation? [This question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717660/mongodb-java-api-difference-between-com-mongodb-dbcollection-save-and-com-mon) says something similar.

Comment: I ran your code and it works for me as is. I still recommend you use update explicitly.  Just replace your coll.save with `coll.update(new BasicDBObject("_id",dbObject.get("_id")), dbObject);`

Answer (score 1):

The *save* call should work on that case, but I suggest you use an *update* with *$addToSet* operation.

Here's the code:

```
DBObject addToSetObj = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
    .push("$addToSet")
        .push("unreadMsgs")
            .add("id", 1)
            .add("unreadMsg", 1)
        .pop()
    .pop()
.get();

// addToSetObj will be { "$addToSet" : { "unreadMsgs" : { "id" : 1 , "unreadMsg" : 1}}}


coll.update(dbQuery, addToSetObj);
Logger.debug("check result: " + coll.findOne(dbQuery).toString());
```

Any doubts on how to use addToSet, check this out: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everybody's answer. I found the real problem. It turns out that my collection is capped, and I am not allowed to insert more data into an existing document in a capped collection. I saw the exception after I changed WriteConcern to FSYNC_SAFE. I changed all my collections to uncapped, and the code works now.